# How to shorten this expression using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following if statement:

```
if not fileName.startswith(".") and re.search("(.exe|.EXE)$", fileName) is not None and not fileName.endswith("-xyz.exe"):
    pass
```

Essentially, I would like to check that the filename does not start with a period and ends with either .exe or .EXE extension, but not with the -xyz.exe extension.  How can I get rid of the startswith and endswith and combine those two checks into the regex itself.

UPDATE: I ask because I want to learn more about regex. Depending on the readability, I will determine if that would be worth making it more concise or not.

UPDATE 2: I ran into this situation.  I always look for opportunities to learn more about regex.  This seems like a good opportunity, so I TRIED to do it MYSELF FIRST until I got stuck.  Please do not give non-regex solution or echo Mark Pilgrim's statement about "now you have 2 problems", because anyone could have done that.  Instead, prove it to me that now I have 2 problems, just like Mark Pilgrim continued with his lesson.  Or show me that it's slick.

Comment: And now you have two problems.

Comment: @Ignacio At least that is better than JAY Z with 99 problems :P

Comment: "learning more about regex" should including learning when NOT to use it.

Comment: Actually, regex works very well for problems exactly like this one (see my answer below for a simple, fast, accurate regex solution).

Comment: @John, learning when not to use regex's requires you to learn regex's.

Comment: By the way, it was Jamie Zawinsky, not Mark Pilgrim who wrote that infamous quote.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Hi Tim. I know you from the UE forum. You turned me on to EPP. Did you know that there is a BETA version of EPP7 - it has some *very* cool features. The matching bracket syntax highlighting is absolutely _amazing!_

Comment: @ridgerunner: Yes, of course. Very intensive beta phase going on there. Can't wait.

Comment: @John Machin: But where or how to learn NOT to use regex.  As Lieven said, you must first learn about it.  Your explanation below is appreciated.  That's how you could help  one to learn by pointing out the mistakes.  I did learn by your answer below.  But I wouldn't have that opportunity to learn from you if I didn't post this question.  Please consider that.

Comment: @ridgerunner: simple fast accurate? Wrong on all 3 counts, like the Holy Roman Empire :)

Comment: @Khnle Do you think that there is no answer that deserve to be accepted ? Do you think that mine is bad ?

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty simple actually:

```py
if re.search(
    r"""# Always use VERBOSE when composing non-trivial regex!
    ^                 # Anchor to start of string.
    # Apply multiple lookahead assertions from string start:
    (?!\.)            # Assert does NOT begin with dot.
    (?=.*\.exe$)      # Assert DOES end with .EXE
    (?!.*-xyz\.exe$)  # Assert does NOT end with -XYZ.EXE
    .*                # Ok to match the filename (optional).
    """, 
    subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

**Edit:** After reading your question a bit closer, it appears you are concerned with the case of the EXE. In that case the regex can easily handle that, too:

```py
if re.search(
    r"""# Always use VERBOSE when composing non-trivial regex!
    ^                     # Anchor to start of string.
    # Apply multiple lookahead assertions from string start:
    (?!\.)                # Assert does not begin with dot.
    (?=.*\.(?:exe|EXE)$)  # Assert DOES end with .EXE or .exe
    (?!.*-xyz\.exe$)      # Assert does NOT end with -xyz-exe
    .*                    # Ok to match the filename (optional).
    """, 
    subject, re.VERBOSE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

**Edit2:**  John Machin has pointed out that with Python, when you are looking for a match that can only occur at the start of a target string, then using the `^` start of string assertion with the `re.search` method is much slower than using `re.match` (and is considered bad practice). With that in mind, here is an improved version:

```py
if re.match(
    r"""# Always use VERBOSE when composing non-trivial regex!
    # Apply multiple lookahead assertions from string start:
    (?!\.)                # Assert does not begin with dot.
    (?=.*\.(?:exe|EXE)$)  # Assert DOES end with .EXE or .exe
    (?!.*-xyz\.exe$)      # Assert does NOT end with -xyz-exe
    .*                    # Ok to match the filename (optional).
    """, 
    subject, re.VERBOSE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Comment: match() is better than search() with `^` anchor; last time I checked, if search fails at position 0, it will try again at position 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: @John Machin - thanks for the tip (although the regex engine will NOT attempt this anywhere but at the beginning - that's what the `^` is for). I know regex but am only a novice with Python.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Your comment is confusing; what is "the regex engine" that behaves better than Python's re?

Comment: @ridgerunner: -1 (1) search with `^` instead of `match` is baroque (2) `$` instead of `\Z` is an error

Comment: @John How is `$` an error? In all regex flavors I am aware of, it means the end of string (or end of line if 'm' multi-line mode is on), and the `\Z` always means end of string (or before the line break at the end of string (if any)). I'm pretty sure this is true with Python as well. Yes?

Comment: @ridgerunner: Looks like you haven't had much to do with POSIX and Perl regexes. Read the manual. Try some examples at the Python interactive prompt.

Comment: @John Machin: Yes, you are right about the `$`. It does match before a linefeed at the end of a file even when multi-line mode is off. (Although it will not match before any other linefeeds unless multi-line mode is on.) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use elementary regular expressions before you start trying to "shorten" your code.

This piece `re.search("(.exe|.EXE)$", fileName)` has THREE deficiencies:

(1) Should use raw strings by habit, even when it makes no difference, because then you (and your readers) don't need to spend time nutting out whether it matters or not.

(2) Unescaped `.` matches ANY character (except a newline (in the default case)).

(3) `$` matches before a newline at the end of a string; you should use `\Z` instead. If you don't, `foo.exe\n` (easy enough to get by mistake if your input was supplied by someone who didn't strip the `\n`) will match.

What you need is `re.search(r"(\.exe|\.EXE)\Z", fileName)`

**Update** for the benefit of anyone who thinks that `re.search("^blahblah", ...)` is a good idea:

```
>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import re;s='x'*100" "re.match(r'foo',s)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import re;s='x'*100" "re.search(r'^foo',s)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.91 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import re;s='x'*1000" "re.match(r'foo',s)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import re;s='x'*1000" "re.search(r'^foo',s)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 usec per loop
```

Comment: Very interesting Thanks for the simple yet telling example. This points to a flaw in the Python regex engine. A regex having only one global alternative which begins with a `^` can never match anywhere but at the start of the string - the engine should be able to see this and stop after failing at the start of the string.

Comment: @ridgerunner: More generally: A regex all of whose global alternatives begin with a `^` can never etc etc

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regexp, just wrap that onto multiple lines and make it a little smarter:

```
if not filename.startswith(".") \
   and filename.lower().endswith(".exe") \
   and not filename.endswith("-xyz.exe"):
    #do stuff
```

Do note that this is slightly different in that `*.eXe`, `*.eXE` and other mixed case versions of the extension would then be ignored as well, unlike in the original.  But I'm betting that it doesn't *really* matter and that my test is better.

**edit**: fixed the `".exe"` part because I had the condition flipped, but if you're trying to learn regular expressions this is a weird contrived example and I think it's best not to try and shoehorn regular expressions as a solution to a problem where it's not a good solution

Comment: Nope, won't work.  Read my question again, more slowly this time.

Comment: You added the latter part to your answer.  That's what I started with too, the most obvious thing.  I want to use this situation to learn more about regex, hence the question.

Comment: @Khnle: you can wax arrogant about wanting regex all you want, you are still wrong and this is a good answer.

Comment: @hop given his update, I can understand why this wouldn't be the answer he's looking for but even though this doesn't answer the (now-updated) question, I'm leaving it for posterity :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
import re

regex = '[^.].*(?:(?<!-xyz).exe|.EXE)'

vectors = (
  '.123.dat',
  '.123.exe',
  '.123.EXE',
  '123.dat',
  '123.exe',
  '123.EXE',
  '.123-xyz.dat',
  '.123-xyz.exe',
  '.123-xyz.EXE',
  '123-xyz.dat',
  '123-xyz.exe',
  '123-xyz.EXE',
)

for v in vectors:
  print "%s: " % (v,),
  if (bool(re.match(regex, v)) == (not v.startswith(".") and
      re.search("(.exe|.EXE)$", v) is not None and
      not v.endswith("-xyz.exe"))):
    print 'PASS'
  else:
    print 'FAIL'
```

Comment: This is slightly different from what is asked. The question is asking to exclude endings with `-xyz.exe`, but not excluding `-xyz.EXE`. Wait, I mistook your answer. Sorry. Or, wait, is your last part the answer, or is your `regex` the answer?

Comment: -1 Dots/periods/whatevers in front of `exe` and `EXE` need escaping, BOTH in your regex AND in your test code! You should use `\Z`, not `$`. You need a `\Z` on the end of your regex. Test cases: `foo@exe`, `foo.exec`, `foo@exe\n`, `foo.exe\n`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pat = re.compile('(?!\.)'
                 '.+'
                 '\.'
                 '(?:(?<!-xyz\.)exe|EXE)'
                 '\Z')

names = ('.123.dat', '.123.exe', '.123.EXE',
         '123.dat', '123.exe', '123.EXE',
         '123-xyz.dat', '123-xyz.exe', '123-xyz.EXE', )

print '\n'.join(v.ljust(18)+str(bool(pat.match(v))) for v in names)
```

.

EDIT:

You are right, ridgerunner, `[^.]` is better than `(?!\.)` : it's more readable, more logic and slightly faster, -4 % (I tested)

.

I also compared `'(?!\.).+?\.(?:EXE|(?<!-xyz)exe)\Z'` ( there is `.+?` instead of `.+`)

With this RE, execution is longer. 
The additional time depends of the number of dots in the tested names.

On names like **'78999.abc.juty.123.dat'** it is around 15 % longer, and on names like **'123.dat'** it's  3 % longer.
I think the reason is that the regex motor examine after each reading of a character if the read character is a dot or not.

On the contrary, with `'.+\.'` the regex motor goes until the end, and then come back to search the last dot. I think it is a correct explanation because, if the RE `'(?!\.).+?\.(?:EXE|(?<!-xyz)exe)\Z'`  is tested on names like **'123.teybertyhbeythbeytberyetynetynetnyetnydat'** , the time is again longer (+ 30 %)

.

I realized that my RE is very similar to the Ignacio's one, and I wondered why I wrote this RE as it seems to have no particular interest. In fact, at the beginning, my idea was to write `'(?!\.).+?(?<=.EXE|(?<!-xyz).exe)\Z'` and then I wrote another string. By the way, with this abandonned RE , the execution time is 25 % longer on short names and 74 % longer on long names.

Finally, when I tested the execution times, **Ignacio's solution is 25 % longer on short names ( '123.dat' ) and 47 % longer on long names ( '78999.abc.juty.123.dat' )**

Best regex is then

```
pat = re.compile('[^.]'
                 '.+'
                 '\.'
                 '(?:(?<!-xyz\.)exe|EXE)'
                 '\Z')
```

I let `'.+'` , not replaced by `'.*'` , because there must be at least 4 characters in the name if we want the name to end with `'.exe'` or `'.EXE'`

Comment: +1 This one works beautifully. (I would only change the first lookahead to simply match one non-dot, i.e. `[^.]`) My solution is meant to illustrate how one can apply multiple assertions to formulate a `X AND NOT Y AND Z' construct and is not as fast as this one. Nice job! (Edit - I gave this an up vote but accidently hit the down one - it won't let me vote it up again unless it is edited. D'oh!)

Comment: @ridgerunner OK, now I understand. Now **khnle** will be aware that writing RE must not be made as copy or translation of the logic of _if_ conditions: regexes have their own logic. With your regex, the regex motor will examine the fist assertion from beginning to end of the string, then will come back to the beginning, and will examine the second assertion, and finally will return to the beginning in order to match all the string from the begining. That's long. -.- I upvote your answer ,and the question , because you don't let you to be impressed by the admonitions of the anti-regex cabalists

Comment: Thanks.  Honestly, it will take me some time to digest everything that you wrote here.  I won't forget to come back here, at least with a + vote and/or mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

That will involve accessing every file that doesn't start with '.' or ends with '-xyz.exe'. The regex module cannot parse stuff outside its namespace. I don't think it's possible, but have you tried checking the module's doc?

Comment: It is possible. But the attempt thus far is not it.